# how to validate ' mark in laravel regex?

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel-5

in my laravel app I have following regex validation,

```
'modelname'    => 'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9. -]+$/|unique:modols|max:255'
```

now I need ad ' symbol also to this modelname how can I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: actually I do not need escape. I need add ' mark also when entering data

Comment: You would enter the escaped quotation mark into your regex. `/^[A-Za-z0-9. -\']+$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `'` to your regex character class:

```
'modelname'    => 'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9. \'-]+$/|unique:modols|max:255'
                                     Here ------^
```

Bear in mind that your regex have the `-` at the end of the character class, if not it will be treated as character class range, if so you will have to escape it with `\-`

Comment: I need apostropy symbol (')

Comment: @Root, yes I added exactly that in my answer